# Using sed to extract and manipulate data

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Z: abcd1 (D2)
Z: abcd2 (D10)
```

Currently I am using this piece of code

```
grep -i Z out.txt | awk '{print "---- " $2 " --- " $3}'
```

To print out something like this:

```
---- abcd1 ---  (D2)
---- abcd2 ---  (D10)
```

How do I pipe sed to the end of awk to remove the brackets and add 2 to each number (Eg: D2 becomes D4 and D10 becomes D12). I cannot change the grep and awk line already there and can only pipe sed.

```
---- abcd1 ---  D4
---- abcd2 ---  D12
```

Comment: *I cannot change* - why that? Is it **locked** or under voltage?

Comment: Don't use sed for arithmetic.  Pipe it to awk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be done without any additional pipe:

```
grep -i 'Z' out.txt \
| awk '{ k=substr($3,2,1); gsub("[^0-9]+","",$3); printf "---- %s --- %s%d\n",$2,k,$3+2 }'
```

The output:

```
---- abcd1 --- D4
---- abcd2 --- D12
```

Comment: I want to do it using an additional pipe only. Without removing the previous awk and grep

Comment: @identical123456, may we know **why**?

Comment: It's complicated. The code is frozen but I can add additional pipes. It is hard to explain

Answer (score 1):

you can do all in one `awk` script,

```
$ awk '/^[zZ]/{gsub(/[()]/,"",$3); print "-----", $2, "---", $3}' file

----- abcd1 --- D2
----- abcd2 --- D10
```

I missed adding 2 part

```
$ awk '/^[zZ]/{gsub(/[()]/,"",$3); 
               d=substr($3,1,1); v=substr($3,2);  
               print "-----", $2, "---", d v+2}' file


----- abcd1 --- D4
----- abcd2 --- D12
```

if you can't change the previous scripts pipe to

```
  ... | awk '{$NF=substr($NF,2,1) substr($NF,3,length($NF)-3)+2}1'

---- abcd1 --- D4
---- abcd2 --- D12
```

Comment: you need to add `2` to the numebers.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed, you can pipe

```
sed 'h;s/\(.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\2/;x;s/[0-9]*$//;x;s/^/echo $((2+/;s/$/))/e;H;x;s/\n//'
```